# Microsoft Cognitive Service Speech Recognition Result to String in C#

Tags: c#

I am going to display my recognition speech result into my C# Window form application. However, I met a problem in converting result into string and display it in my textbox.

Attach here with my code:
In my Voice.cs

```
namespace GUI_FYP
{
class Voice
{
    public static async Task<RecognitionResult> RecognizeSpeechAsync()
    {
        var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "southeastasia");

        using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config))
        {
            var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
            return result;

        }
    }

}
}
```

In my Form.cs

```
private void VoiceStart_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Voice.RecognizeSpeechAsync().Wait();
        string command = Voice.RecognizeSpeechAsync().Result.ToString;
        VoiceBox.Text = command;

    }
```

But my error shows this:
[image]

Comment: `.ToString();` You're missing the parenthesis.

Comment: Hi, when i clicked the button, it should display the return string to my textbox. but the text does not show in textbox. Could i know whats the issue ? thanks

Comment: I found out after i pressed the button to execute my speech recognition, the whole application freeze. Do i miss any important steps?

Comment: That's probably a separate question really. You seem to be calling the method twice, once using `.Wait()`, and then again immediately afterwards using `.Result.Tostring();`, rather than storing the result of the first call and acting on it, something like: `var result = await Voice.RecognizeSpeechAsync();`. Have you stepped through in a debugger to find out which line it's hanging on?

Comment: i tried the debugger , it seem like the line of "var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();" is in error. i am not sure whether is my return method wrong or anything else

Comment: Problem solved, thank you!